# apache2 and VirtualHost with foreign characters and more than one Alias

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, serveralias

I have a simple apache2 setup with two VirtualHosts. One is a domain name with "normal" characters, and one has foreign characters (with punycode).

The problem is that I don't know how to add "www" as an alias with the punycode domain. With the "normal" one it works fine.

Here's the "normal" host:

```
ServerName aev25.no
ServerAlias www.aev25.no
```

I can access the correct site with both the name and the alias.

Here's the "foreign"/punycode host:

```
ServerName xn--hvin-gra.no
ServerAlias høvin.no
```

Now, since I haven't got an Alias with "www", it naturally won't work like that. But if I try adding another alias, like this:

```
ServerName xn--hvin-gra.no
ServerAlias høvin.no
ServerAlias www.høvin.no
```

or this:

```
ServerName xn--hvin-gra.no
ServerAlias høvin.no www.høvin.no
```

it doesn't work. It just opens the default apache2 site. So it seems that this is not the correct way to do it, even though apache2 doesn't complain.

I also have a setup for the domain aev25.no, where the ServerAlias is www.aev25.no. That works fine, which should show that the problem is not related to www.*.:

```
ServerName aev25.no
ServerAlias wwwaev25.no
```

(works fine)

So, how do I add another Alias to the domain? Or should I do this another way?

NB: The apache2 version is 2.2.22.

Comment: Have you got your dns configured for the alias? Does www.høvin.no resolve to the server ip address?

Comment: Yes, the dns is correct. I just edited that into the post, since I forgot to mention it. høvin.no opens the correct site, while www.høvin.no just opens the default apache site ("default" from sites-available/enabled).

Comment: Can you rename `default-site` file to something like `z-default`, to make sure it is processed at last, and see if it helps?

Comment: Not sure if I know what you mean. Do you mean rename /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default? If so, I tried that during the troubleshooting, and it didn't have any effect on anything. The way this version of apache2 works - possibly all newer versions? - is that I try accessing a sub domain or alias for a site that doesn't exist, it defaults to the default page. What I know is that høvin.no works, as the correct site is opened. But any extra Aliases - www.høvin.no, test.høvin.no etc - just opens the default page.

Comment: I also forgot to mention: I have a similar setup for the domain aev25.no, where www.aev25.no is the ServerAlias. That works fine, so the problem is not related to www.* I'd say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't test it but I have a vague recollection of reading somewhere that you need to use punycode in both the ServerName and ServerAlias directives. I would try

```
ServerAlias    www.xn--hvin-gra.no
```

I got the `www.xn--hvin-gra.no` by entering www.høvin.no into a random punycode converter.

---

I did a  simple google search and this is correct [apache serveralias punycode](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=serveralias+punycode&oq=serveralias+punycode)

Comment: This is correct; the reason is that translation from UTF-8 to punycode happens in the client, not in apache. You would have to use the same conversion in e.g. nginx. See https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/ for links to the relevant RFCs.

Comment: You're right. That was the only thing I didn't try yet because I read that you should NOT use punycode in the ServerAlias.